# Perform curve fitting on jagged curve in OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, curve-fitting

I am doing some research about processing optical power intensity data.
I want to perform curve fitting on jagged curve shown in the figure.

[Desired curve fitting manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwDbA.jpg)

The first thing I tried is Fourier transform, but it is not very convenient;
so I am searching a methodology by OpenCV.
I have google Documentation and find "Contour" section,
but nothing satisfied my goal.
If you have any idea about processing this curve please told we.
I will appreciate you with great thanks!

Here is my raw data:
[You can preview on web browser :)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/74lhwv1q0ed9qy7/Sheet1.csv?dl=0)

Comment: You should probably do the fitting on the actual data, not on the visualization.

Comment: I agree with @TA. Try to find local min and max and use B-spline interpolation to get your curve (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline).
If you want more help try to provide input data.

Comment: Thank you for informing B-spline. I have now uploaded my raw data.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html might help

Comment: Looks like you can first perform some smoothing and then detect the envelop of the signal.

Comment: Also from your final curve, it seems that you want to ignore outlier. so maybe apply median filter to the raw data. and then you can apply convex hull on it to get rough curve. You need to find sutiable window size though.